# Replacing default __dict__ for object with OrderedDict

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have two classes in my code. `first` is the parent, which `second` inherits.

```
class first(object):
    def __init(self,**kwargs):  
        pass

    def __setattr__(self,name,value):
        self.__dict__[name] = value

class second(first):
    def do_something(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
```

when I am printing the class  second (by e.g. `second.__dict__`) I get the unordered dictionary. This is obvious. I want to change this behavior to get an ordered dictionary using the `OrderedDict` class, but it does not work. I am changing implementation of `first` in the following way:

```
class first(OrderedDict):   
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):  
        super(first,self).__init__(**kwargs)  
    def __setattr__(self,name_value):  
        super(first,self).__setattr__(name_value)
```

I would like to print `second` using `__dict__` or `__repr__`, but I got the unordered dictionary. What should I change?

Comment: The `__dict__` of `OrderDict` instances is not itself an `OrderedDict` instance...

Comment: Could you explain *why* you want this? There might be other approaches you could explore.

Comment: Why do you _need_ the `__dict__` to be ordered? Plain `dict`s are more efficient, and for printing you can simply sort the dict in your `__repr__` or `__str__` methods.

Comment: I would like to have an order of elements the same as in moment of creating them. I print such info on the screen and order matters. Sorting in this case does not help.

Comment: @PM 2Ring: The `OrderDict` items might need to be kept is some order that can't be simulated by simply sorting them. One real-world example might be to simply maintain the order in which they were added/created. I suppose that could simulated, too, but the point is that it shouldn't take that much effort to do so when an `OrderedDict` already can (and is likely much faster).

Comment: @martineau Fair point. But of course this is a non-issue for Python 3.6+, since plain `dict` now maintains insertion order.

Comment: Yes this question is obsolete in 3.7 [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)

Answer (score 12):

You can simply redirect all attribute access to an `OrderedDict`:

```
class first(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        self._attrs = OrderedDict(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self._attrs[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == '_attrs':
            return super(first, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        self._attrs[name] = value
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> class first(object):
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
...         self._attrs = OrderedDict(*args, **kwargs)
...     def __getattr__(self, name):
...         try:
...             return self._attrs[name]
...         except KeyError:
...             raise AttributeError(name)
...     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...         if name == '_attrs':
...             return super(first, self).__setattr__(name, value)
...         self._attrs[name] = value
... 
>>> class second(first):
...     def do_something(self):
...         self.a = 1
...         self.b = 2
...         self.c = 3
... 
>>> s = second()
>>> s.do_something()
>>> s._attrs
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
```

You can't otherwise replace the `__dict__` attribute with an `OrderedDict` instance, because Python optimises instance attribute access by using the concrete class API to access the dictionary internals in C, bypassing the `OrderedDict.__setitem__` hook altogether (see [issue #1475692](https://bugs.python.org/issue1475692)).

Comment: Thank you very much for this demo. In fact it works in this simple example, but after implementing this in my freaky code I got an error:  RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded. i am looking for the bug in code, but in the meantime maybe you could find the reason of this issue? Or propose alternative solution to avoid such an issue. I would like to not increment recursion depth.

Comment: @Przemo: your `__setattr__` is calling itself perhaps? How are you using `super()` here? Make sure you guard against setting `_attrs` in the wrong object as well.

Comment: @Przemo: increasing the recursion depth is not going to solve this issue, you have an *infinite* loop there.

Comment: I got one calling of __setattr__ method and then many of callings of __getattr__. It will try with your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @Przemo: right, that means you do not yet have a specific attribute that `__setattr__` tried to access. Your `_attrs` attribute is probably missing, so `self._attrs[name]` calls `__getattr__('_attrs)`, which tries to use `self._attrs[name]`, which doesn't exist, so it calls `__getattr__`, etc.

Comment: @Przemo: this is why my `__setattr__` method explicitly tests for `_attrs` *first* and makes sure it is set by calling the original version via `super()`.

Comment: I'd drop the `**kwargs` as it packs things into a regular dict in between. `first(**OrderedDict([...]))` looses the order.

Comment: @Suki: how about using `*args`, in addition?

Comment: @Martijn great, that way the call signature matches an `OrderedDict`.

Comment: Seems like this approach would generally slow down _all_ attribute access because now they require either a `__getattr__()` or `__setattr__()` call.

Comment: @martineau: which is why you can't just replace the `__dict__` attribute either (which would require Python to call `__setitem__` on whatever replaced the `dict` instance currently used).

Comment: Martijn: Hmm...I understand the point you're making (and have read the linked bug-report which indicates the issue is still open), However, if you actually try it out, it seems that one **_can_** just replace `__dict__` with an `OrderdDict` in the class' `__init__` method as shown in  @Kresimir's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32699282/355230)—at least with Python 2.7.14 and 3.6.5. What am I missing?

Comment: @martineau: sure you can, but you can't actually set attributes *and store them in the `OrderedDict` in a way that keeps them ordered*.

Comment: @martineau: what happens is that `OrderedDict` is a subclass of `dict`, and the normal `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` implementation for instances (in C) just reaches into the C-level data structures. The custom `__setitem__` method of the `OrderedDict` class is not consulted. When you actually print the `__dict__` reference you'll be shown an empty `OrderedDict` instance, because all the internal order-recording structure is not being maintained. `list(d.__dict__)` is empty, so is `list(d.__dict__.items())`, and only `len(d.__dict__)` is correct. The keys are stored though.

Comment: Martijn: Ah, OK, now I get it. Note however if I `print(test.__dict__)` the result shown is not empty—it's `OrderedDict([('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)])`—and the attribute order is maintained after a `test.a, test.b, test.c = 'a', 'b', 'c'` assignment. However _adding_ a new item with `test.foo = 42` doesn't change it contents. Thanks for bearing with me in making sense of the subject. I would think a metaclass could probably get around the problem caused by the "issue" (which the Python devs seem in no hurry to fix...)

Comment: @MartijnPieters it is 2022 now and since python 3.6 the __dict__ is a OrderedDict by default. In addition someone could use `__prepare__` nowadays. Would you mind updating your answer?

Comment: @Thingamabobs: no, `__dict__` is a `dict` object, not an `OrderedDict`. `dict` preserves insertion order, but **is not reorderable**, where `OrderedDict` *can* be reordered. There are still cases where you want an `OrderedDict` instead of the base `dict`.

Answer (score 5):

I think the solutions in this thread focus too much on using `OrderedDict` as if it is a necessity. The class already has a builtin `__dict__` method, the only problem is ordering the keys. Here is how I am retrieving `(key, value)` pairs from my class in the order they are entered:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        self._keys = []
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        self.arg3 = arg3

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        # store new attribute (key, value) pairs in builtin __dict__
        self.__dict__[key] = value
        # store the keys in self._keys in the order that they are initialized
        # do not store '_keys' itelf and don't enter any key more than once 
        if key not in ['_keys'] + self._keys:
            self._keys.append(key)

    def items(self):
        # retrieve (key, value) pairs in the order they were initialized using _keys
        return [(k, self.__dict__[k]) for k in self._keys]

>>> x = MyClass('apple', 'orange', 'banana')
>>> print x.items()
[('arg1', 'apple'), ('arg2', 'orange'), ('arg3', 'banana')]
>>> x.arg1 = 'pear'
>>> print x.items()
[('arg1', 'pear'), ('arg2', 'orange'), ('arg3', 'banana')]
```

I'm using a class to store about 70 variables used to configure and run a much bigger program. I save a text copy of the initial `(key, value)` pairs that can be used to initialize new instances of the class. I also save a text copy of the `(key, value)` pairs after running the program because several of them are set or altered during the program run. Having the `(key, value)` pairs in order simply improves the readability of the text file when I want to scan through the results.

Comment: This approach would also work well for pre-2.7 versions of Python that don't have a built-in `collections.OrderedDict`. Store new values wouldn't be quite a fast, since doing so now requires a linear search...on the other hand, reading values of existing attribute would be just a fast as it normally would be (i.e. doesn't force all accesses to go through `__getattr__()` or `__setattr__()` calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by actually replacing __dict__ with OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = OrderedDict()
        self.__dict__['a'] = 0
        self.__dict__['b'] = 1
        self.__dict__['c'] = 2

test = Test()
print test.__dict__
test.a, test.b, test.c = 'a', 'b', 'c'
print test.__dict__
```

This should printout:

```
OrderedDict([('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)])
OrderedDict([('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c')])
```

Comment: This looks like a bad idea. I don't know exactly what's happening, but i think the `OrderedDict` is ending up in the `'__dict__'` slot of the real `__dict__`, and all kinds of unpredictable nonsense is happening.

Try it again without the `self.__dict__['a'] = 0` lines and see.

Comment: @mdaoust: Replacing the instance's  `__dict__` with another mapping object is fine. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__).

Comment: @mdaoust: Sorry, my earlier comment that doing something like was fine was **incorrect**. See the end of Martijn Pieters' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27941731/355230) (and the comments under it) for more details.

Comment: @mdaoust Actually I think your earlier comment is right. The [issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/43272) is unrelated, it just says the __getitem__ is not correctly recognized in attribute lookup. [My code](https://github.com/ZhiyuanChen/DanLing/blob/develop/danling/runner/runner.py) works perfect

Answer (score -1):

Another option; you can also manipulate **new** if you wish.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
class OrderedClassMeta(type):
    @classmethod
        def __prepare__(cls, name, bases, **kwds):
        return OrderedDict()
class OrderedClass(metaclass=OrderedClassMeta):
    pass

class A(OrderedClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b=1
        self.a=2
    def do(self):
        print('do')
class B(OrderedClass):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a=1
        self.b=2
    def do(self):
        print('do')

 a=A()
 print(a.__dict__)
 b=B()
 print(b.__dict__)
```

Comment: Please try your answer before posting, it doesn't work. The return value of `__prepare__` gets copied to a standard dict in C. See https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-January/618121.html.

Comment: There was indentation issue the original post (for "def __prepare__").  If you clean the indentation, and using Python 3.6, the result look as follows: <code> 
>>> a=A()
>>> print(a.__dict__)
{'b': 1, 'a': 2}
>>> b=B()
>>> print(b.__dict__)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> </code>